# Google cloud asset assets.list REST API Quota exceeded error returned

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-asset-inventory

I'm trying to use cloud asset inventory assets.list REST API request from **my code** and after reaching the maximum quota I get the following error: "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'ListAssets Requests' and limit 'ListAssets Requests per minute' of service 'cloudasset.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:ProjectNumber'" where the ProjectNumber I get match the project-id of my project and I can also see the requests made under the quotes tab in Cloud Asset API.

However When I'm using the "**Try this method**" in "https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/assets/list" above the quota limit I getthe same quota error but with some ProjectNumber I don't recognize (doesn't match the project-id of my project) and I also can't see the requests made under the quotes tab.

I would appreciate an explanation of the reason I get a project number I don't recognize when using the second method? who own this project number?

Comment: Which type of credentials are you using (user or service account) in your **my code** problem. User credentials can be API rate limited. For your second question, **Try this method** uses an OAuth Client from a Google managed account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use "Try this method", you're leveraging a Google-owned project.

The Google-owned project is the one that backs the APIs Explorer
s "Try this method" (OAuth2) client and the project that has all Google's APIs enabled.

A similar approach is used by `gcloud` when you use [`gcloud auth application-default`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default) though I assume it's a different project.

In both cases, think of these as Google (not your) applications and, as with any (!) application that requires credentials, in these cases, Google must provide a project that enables OAuth2 and enables the appropriate APIs.

> **NOTE** This mechanism helps explain why, sometimes when using either of these Google applications, the user may find "Service X is not enabled [for project ...]". In this case, Google has not enabled the API in the backing project and so the developer is unable to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Can you please mention a source regarding this topic? so I can learn a bit more about this mechanism I couldn't find it in the documentations

Comment: You're welcome! You know, I don't know where this explained. I'm a former Googler and just know it.